# Linking Use Cases in Sparx Enterprise Architect

Tags: enterprise-architect

I am trying to link a Use Case in one diagram to a diagram that will detail this use case.

What I am doing is:

- Create new Use case diagram (Right click on Model -> Add -> Add Diagram)
- Call the diagram "Test"
- In diagram add use case (Right click in diagram - > New Element or Connector -> Use case)
- Call the Use case "Test Link"
- Select "Test Link" and add Use case diagram (Right click on "Link Test" -> Add -> Add Diagram)
- Call the new diagram Test Link Diagram"

What I expected now was to be able to double click on "Test Link" and that would take me to the "Test Link Diagram". What happens is that it opens a property windows.

Does anyone know how I can link a use case to a use case diagram?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fixed it. The trick was Right Click on the Use case - > Advanced -> Make Composite

Comment: And if you want other child diagram than Use case:
`Right click on Use case in Project browser -> Add -> Select Composite Diagram`

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, as of 2017 (using Enterprise Architect 12.0), the problem still persists. It seems that, although the

> Right Click on Use Case -> New Child Diagram -> Add Diagram

approach adds the desired child diagram, the link is not established. In order to achieve that, one has to go through a second cycle of clicking as follows:

> Right Click on Use Case -> New Child Diagram -> Select Composite Diagram

The pop-up window should already have pre-selected the child diagram created in the first step. Click on OK, and you’ll be rewarded with a use case that has the link symbol in the lower right corner. Now a double click will open the child diagram.

Comment: This should be marked as the answer. The other answer is either outdated or just wrong.